# Microsoft graph API: getting 403 while trying to read user groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get user's group information who log-Ins into the application.

Using below code, when I am hitting `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}`, then I am able to see that user is exist (200), but when trying to hit `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/memberOf`, then I am getting 403.

```
private static async Task Test()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "TOKEN HERE");

            var user = "testuser@onmicrosoft.com";
            var userExist = await DoesUserExistsAsync(client, user);

            Console.WriteLine($"Does user exists?  {userExist}");

            if (userExist)
            {
                var groups = await GetUserGroupsAsync(client, user);

                foreach (var g in groups)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Group:  {g}");
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task<bool> DoesUserExistsAsync(HttpClient client, string user)
    {
        var payload = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}");

        return true;
    }

    private static async Task<string[]> GetUserGroupsAsync(HttpClient client, string user)
    {
        var payload = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/memberOf");
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(payload);
        var groupDescription = from g in obj["value"]
                               select g["displayName"].Value<string>();

        return groupDescription.ToArray();
    }
```

Is this something related to permission issue, my token has below scope now,

[image]

Note - Over here I am not trying to access other user/group information, only who log-ins. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `/v1.0/users/[a user]/memberOf` requires your access token to have either Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All or Directory.AccessAsUser.All and this is
documented at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof.

A great way to test this API call before implementing it in code is to use the [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) where you can change which permissions your token has by using the "modify permissions" dialog.

Comment: This Graph Explorer really helped me to solve my development issue. Thanks for that link.